# I get an error when I print b1 and b3 seperatly.. But thers no error if I print b2 seperatly ..Pls Explaine

Tags: java, byte

```
class Example{
public static void main(String args[]){
int x=100;
final int y=100;
final int z;
z=100;

byte b1,b2,b3;
b1=x;
b2=y;
b3=z;

System.out.println(b1); 
}
```

}
I get an error when I print b1 and b3 seperatly.. But thers no error if I print b2 seperatly ..Pls Explaine

Comment: Pls Explaine the question

Comment: Examining the error and the failing code would be a good start.

Comment: error code: Example.java:12: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte

Comment: @AsansaRushan: `x` is of type `int`. `b1` is of type `byte`. `byte` is smaller than `int`, so `b1 = x` may lose data, because a `byte` isn't big enough to hold an `int`. (It won't in your specific code, because 100 fits in a `byte`. But if you had `x = 5230`, `b1` would end up being 110.) This has nothing whatsoever to do with printing.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanx for the rply,, But y is a int too if I commented both b1=x; and b3=z and put a  s.o.p (b2); after compiling  I got an output as 100 without error

Answer (score 1):

A `byte` can only hold values from -128 to +127.  If your `int` were to contain, say, 5000, that would be a problem.  Explicitly casting to a `(byte)` is how you say, in Java, "I know what I'm doing, stop bugging me."

Now, the reason that it works with `b2=y` is because it knows at compile time that `y=100` and thus this operation is safe.  It has no such guarantees about `x` and `z`.

Answer (score 0):

> If you make any variable as final, you cannot change the value of
>   final variable(It will be constant).

[Source](http://www.javatpoint.com/final-keyword)

`z` is `final`, therefore it is constant. However, it is not initialized at declaration. Later a value is assigned to it, but it won't matter. You then assign `z` to `b3` and print it out, but `z` is `final` and a value is only assigned to it after declaration. Since it is unclear what should be printed out, you get an error. Try with

```
final int z = 100;
```

instead.